# how to solve rselenium error with tor browser in windows

Tags: rstudio, tor, rselenium

I want access Tor browswer anonymously because of dynamic ip address.

recommendation script([Tor Browser with RSelenium in Linux/Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048810/tor-browser-with-rselenium-in-linux-windows)) is :

```
library(RSelenium)
browserP <- "C:/Users/dldbgud/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/firefox.exe"
jArg <- paste0("-Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=\"", browserP, "\"")
pLoc <- "C:/Users/dldbgud/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.meek-http-helper/"
jArg <- c(jArg, paste0("-Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=\"", pLoc, "\""))
selServ <- RSelenium::startServer(javaargs = jArg)
```

But, i get a message this :

> Error: startServer is now defunct. Users in future can find the function in 
>   file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "examples/serverUtils"). The
>   recommended way to run a selenium server is via Docker. Alternatively
>   see the RSelenium::rsDriver function.

Why i getted the error message?

Also, other method ok this :

```
port=4445 
shell(paste0("cd C:/Users/dldbgud/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser & java -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin='firefox.exe' -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -port ",port,""), wait = FALSE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "firefox",port = port,remoteServerAddr ="localhost")
remDr$open()
```

But, Not execute Tor browser, firefox. 
I want to execute Tor browser including dynamic ip address.
Help me please!!